# How to change the default google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Recently I've found out [a way](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) to change google maps appearance as the following image suggests

[image]

In the help menu, it is adviced that `JSON` can be used to modify the default map or create a new style. Even though I can get the code and understand its meaning, I don't know how and where to use it to create a black and white map style. How can I do that?

The code is

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#ffffff" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#000000" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#ffffff" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#ffffff" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Google suggests [a way](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#styling_the_default_map) but I don't know how to apply it. Where is `MapOptions` for instance?

Any ideas are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a FULL example for you to follow:
I added it all here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps</title>

        <style> #map-canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 400px; width: 100%; }
        </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
  function initialize() {

    var styles = [
    {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "stylers": [
        { "color": "#ffffff" }
      ]
    },{
      "featureType": "road",
      "stylers": [
        { "color": "#000000" }
      ]
    },{
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        { "color": "#ffffff" }
      ]
    },{
      "featureType": "poi",
      "stylers": [
        { "color": "#ffffff" }
      ]
    }
  ];

    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,{name: "Styled Map"});
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The problem isn't the code, but where do I have to add this code?

Comment: <script> HERE </script>, which is inside the <head> tags of your html code.  Make sure you add this too:     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

Comment: I see. The thing is that this code http://pastebin.com/TmhCehKC doesn't prosuce any map at all...

Comment: add this <div id="map-canvas"></div> to your html

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple  go see the html+javascript for a full example

Comment: There must be something wrong with my system. I pasted the exact code at your link and all I get is a blank page. Should I set something to make it work?

Comment: add this to header -
      <style>
      #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 400px;
 width: 100%;
      }
      </style>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38946/discussion-between-jonco91-and-thanos)