# Make google map monochrom

Tags: google-maps

This is my code for google map with custom marker.

```
    <script>
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      scrollwheel: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6328215, 22.9468210), //* Add here your coordinates, here is where the map will center *//
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
  disableDefaultUI: true
    });
    var icons = {
      Church: {
        name: 'Church',
        icon: 'images/map/pin.png'  //* Add here the Church Pin *//
      }
    };
    function addMarker(location) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location.position,
        icon: icons[location.type].icon,
        map: map
      });
    }
    var locations = [
      {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6328215, 22.9468210),  //* Add here the Church coordinates *//
        type: 'Church'
      }
    ];
    for (var i = 0, location; location = locations[i]; i++) {
      addMarker(location);
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

How can add stylers to this code so the colour of the map will become black and white?

I know that I need to add something like this:

```
    stylers: [
    {saturation: '-100'}
]
```

I just don't know how to do it! 
Can someone please tell how to do this?

Thank you all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the default google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278782/how-to-change-the-default-google-maps)

Comment: related question: [Short delay in loading google maps style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626783/short-delay-in-loading-google-maps-style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several sample on the net    here you can find a collection

> https://snazzymaps.com/explore?color=white
>
> this is a [sample greyscale](https://snazzymaps.com/style/15/subtle-grayscale)
>
> ```
> [
>     {
>         "featureType": "landscape",
>         "stylers": [
>             {
>                 "saturation": -100
>             },
>             {
>                 "lightness": 65
>             },
>             {
>                 "visibility": "on"
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "featureType": "poi",
>         "stylers": [
>             {
>                 "saturation": -100
>             },
>             {
>                 "lightness": 51
>             },
>             {
>                 "visibility": "simplified"
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "featureType": "road.highway",
>         "stylers": [
>             {
>                 "saturation": -100
>             },
>             {
>                 "visibility": "simplified"
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "featureType": "road.arterial",
>         "stylers": [
>             {
>                 "saturation": -100
>             },
>             {
>                 "lightness": 30
>             },
>             {
>                 "visibility": "on"
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "featureType": "road.local",
>         "stylers": [
>             {
>                 "saturation": -100
>             },
>             {
>                 "lightness": 40
>             },
>             {
>                 "visibility": "on"
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "featureType": "transit",
>         "stylers": [
>             {
>                 "saturation": -100
>             },
>             {
>                 "visibility": "simplified"
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "featureType": "administrative.province",
>         "stylers": [
>             {
>                 "visibility": "off"
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "featureType": "water",
>         "elementType": "labels",
>         "stylers": [
>             {
>                 "visibility": "on"
>             },
>             {
>                 "lightness": -25
>             },
>             {
>                 "saturation": -100
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     {
>         "featureType": "water",
>         "elementType": "geometry",
>         "stylers": [
>             {
>                 "hue": "#ffff00"
>             },
>             {
>                 "lightness": -25
>             },
>             {
>                 "saturation": -97
>             }
>         ]
>     }
> ]
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was not 100% what I wanted but it helped me a lot!

Comment: I upvoted and accepted your answer as right! Thank you.